# Why does a slightly out of specs power supply works and what are the possible consequences?

Tags: power-supply, amperage, security

I have the following lamp:

[image]

Its power supply is rated at 5.6V and 2.68A blew up some time ago.

I then went to an electronics shop where I've been suggested that I could replace it by a universal power supply for laptop.

I did and it worked well for years but then the universal power supply, which was rated at 5V and 4A finally blew up as well.

Now I have at hand an USB power supply like the following, it can supply 5V and up to 2.4A:

[image]

As I heard that some appliances can deal with a slightly out of spec voltage, I decided to give it a try and it worked.

Luckily, the USB power supply manual says that if it's asked to deliver more amps that it can actually do, it will shut itself down.

So I suppose it's *"okay"* but well ... I don't really have any electrical knowledge to support my theory!

**Question, two-folded:**

- why does a slightly out of specs power supply works in this case?

  - and can one assume it is safe to use it or is it strongly discouraged?

(as you might have guessed, the product ran out of production so I can no longer get a replacement power supply for it)

**Edit:**

The lamp is a Philips Living Colors (1st gen. from 2008), it is rated at 15W, the 5.6V/2.68A power supply plugs on 220V and the lamp is not chargeable.

Pretty difficult to find much more information than that even though it's relatively recent.

FWIW, there is some stuff about its internals [in this link](http://www.knutsel.org/2009/01/01/livingcolors-1st-generation/).

Comment: Such a question is not allowed here, because it critically depends on knowledge of product details which are not knowable.

Comment: Current limiting does not protect against out of spec voltage if out of spec voltage ends up mattering. Out of spec by being lower is *probably* safer than out of spec by being higher.

Comment: is it a rechargeable lamp or just a lamp with an external power supply? you didn't give us the spec of your lamps.. can you edit it to add more picture of your lamps? usually all electronics have a label on it

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that, just added details I could find about it.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to make sense - you say at the end it runs from 220 VAC and is not chargeable yet you are talking about a charger throughout.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought it made sense, the charger plugs on 220V.

Comment: What you’re talking about is a power supply, not a charger...

Comment: Yes, you're right actually ... I've updated the question accordingly!

Comment: It's great that you're no longer using mistaken wording, but the question is still fundamentally *off topic* as it relies on unknowable details of product internals

Comment: I perfectly understood that people would need to see its internals to further suggest an answer, thing is, I've tried to open it up but it's tightly sealed in a way that prevents that ... unless I guess you have the appropriate servicing tool, which I don't as you might have guessed.

Answer (score 2):

Because

1. The lamp works okay with 5V, and
2. It doesn't draw more current than the USB brick can supply. Maybe it draws slightly less current when provided with 5V instead of 5.6V, or maybe the original power supply just had some headroom (as indeed it should have).

Neither of these things *had* to be true, and there's no way to predict whether it works (or "why" it works) without cracking open the device and studying it, so we can't really say more.

As to whether it's safe — if your USB charger has *really* been tested to shut off under an overcurrent condition rather than melt or catch on fire, then that's good, but some manufacturers are more than willing to lie about such things. The lamp looks like a Philips, so it's probably designed not to let a simple undervoltage cause irreparable harm. But since you're operating both lamp and charger outside of their sticker specs, there are really no promises. Disaster is unlikely, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hell aybe,

I helped designed hundreds of chargers in the past, including the first-inch cube charger for the big A company, so here is my take.

To answer your question,

1. A slightly out of spec charger would work; however, you cannot guarantee the safety of it because of the following reason.
   a. The device-side (the side the charge plugs into, may have a tight tolerance due to cost-cutting.) The higher the input voltage and current tolerance, the more dangerous it is for the device or even the charge to blow up due to overheating of the internal component (most due to output capacitor).
   b. This can also just be a "bad" tolerance of the output capacitor blowing up, so an experienced EE person could easily replace that cap with a higher quality cap.
   c. Your initial charge is rated for 15W (5.6V x 2.68A), and your second charger is rated for 20W (5V x 4A), so for a lamp, assuming it is not a LED, which needs a different kind of "charger" which they call it a "Driver", some lamp requires a constant voltage and constant current, so just be aware of that.
2. I think the picture that I see is a multiport USB charger and it is designed to meet the USB charging specs not source to drive a 15W lamp so I think it's not ideal to do so. Makes sense to find an old power adapter that is as close to your OEM specs as possible or just buy a new lamp at this point. I used the word charger to answer your question, but I would call this a power adapter since it is not charging anything, it is to convert to voltage to power your lamp.

I hope this helps.